# How to have alternating layouts for children of ExpandableListView

Tags: android

I have an ExpandableListView with a scroll listener that let's the user scroll down endlessly by fetching the new data in the background.

I want to have my child items (text views basically) have alternating background color.

here is what I did in my adapter to achieve the desired result:

```
   @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        TextView textView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsitem, null);
        }


        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.newsContent);

        if ( (childPosition % 2) == 0 )
        {
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#123123"));
        }

        textView.setTypeface(fontContent);
        convertView.setTag(textView);


        if (groupPosition ==0 && parentItems.get(0).News == null)
        {
            textView.setText("uzgunuz henuz bugun icin haber yok :(");
        }
        else {
            child = parentItems.get(groupPosition).News.get(childPosition);
            textView.setText(groupPosition + "-" + childPosition +" "+ child.Content);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

when the items are initially loaded, everything works perfectly.

[image]

but when I scroll down, I see the new items have random background color:

[image]

If I keep scrolling down and up a few times, I realize even the items that were initially loaded with the correct layout gets messed up:

[image]

Please note: I tried manually loading new items without using a scroll listener, right after the initialization of the expandablelistview. The result is the same.

Also the numbers in the beginning of each child item in the screenshots represent groupnumber-childnumber, they are all correct. So there is nothing wrong with the ordering as I initially thought.

I also tried using alternated layouts for child items instead of modifying the background color of the textview. didn't work.

How can I achieve the desired solution? Where am I messing it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if ( (childPosition % 2) == 0 )
    {
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#123123"));
    }
```

You forgot the `else` condition, to set the color back to the default. Views are recycled; you need to update *everything* in a view, as otherwise you will wind up with recycled state.

Comment: You sir, just saved a life. I was about to cut my wrists

Comment: @Zagoda: Generally speaking, that's not a recommended debugging technique. :-)